# How to pass links with values to pahe2.php

Tags: php

This is a fragment of my code, that get all users from Active Directory (some fields). The first column (user_name) is a reference to the page2.php where I can see User profile more detail. The problem is page1.php passes only  last values of the link from the cycle. How can I do that, any dynamic link of the user passes its information. Could you help me? Thanks. $info is an array of LDAP data.

**Here is my code:**

```
<?php for ($i=0; $i<$info["count"]; $i++) {             
        $res=$info[$i];

    $m_name=$res["displayname"];  
        $m_title=$res["title"];       
        $m_dep=$res["department"];    
        $m_tel=$res["telephonenumber"];
        $m_mail=$res["mail"];
        ?>

<?php echo '<div class="column"><h5><a href="user.php" target="_blank">'.$m_name[0].'</a></h5></div>'?>
<?php echo '<div class="column"><h5>'.$m_title[0].'</h5></div>'?>
<?php echo '<div class="column"><h5>'.$m_tel[0].'</h5></div>'?>
<?php echo '<div class="column"><h5>'.$m_tel[0].'</h5></div>'?>
<?php echo '<div class="column"><h5>'.$m_mail[0].'</h5></div>'?>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Are you asking about [`$_GET`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php)?

Comment: I think something  $_Sessions array..

Comment: How to add Sessions in to the cycle..

Answer (score 0):

Depending on exactly what you are trying to do, you can do it in two ways. Based on what you described, and your comment about Sessions, you can pass information from page to page using a session.

http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['displayname'] = $res["displayname"]; 
$_SESSION['title'] = $res["title"];       
$_SESSION['department'] = $res["department"];    
$_SESSION['telephonenumber'] = $res["telephonenumber"];
$_SESSION['mail'] = $res["mail"];
```

And then on Page2, read the values back or use them directly on the page:

```
$name = $_SESSION['displayname'];
```

or

```
echo 'Hello ' . $_SESSION['displayname'] . ' how are you?';
```

But if Page1 is a list of all users, how would you determine what information to store in the session for passing to Page2?

It would make more sense to me to use GET parameters to pass information from page to page.  So, for example, if Page1 is a list of all users, and Page2 information about a single user, you could structure your loop like this:

```
<?php for ($i=0; $i<$info["count"]; $i++) {             
        $res=$info[$i];

    $m_name=$res["displayname"];  
        $m_title=$res["title"];       
        $m_dep=$res["department"];    
        $m_tel=$res["telephonenumber"];
        $m_mail=$res["mail"];
        ?>

<?php echo '<div class="column"><h5><a href="user.php?id=' . $someuniqueidfromLDAP . '" target="_blank">'.$m_name[0].'</a></h5></div>'?>
<?php echo '<div class="column"><h5>'.$m_title[0].'</h5></div>'?>
<?php echo '<div class="column"><h5>'.$m_tel[0].'</h5></div>'?>
<?php echo '<div class="column"><h5>'.$m_tel[0].'</h5></div>'?>
<?php echo '<div class="column"><h5>'.$m_mail[0].'</h5></div>'?>
<?php } ?>
```

The unique ID from LDAP is just that.  Something unique to that user that you can use to search on Page2 and pull out all of the details you want to print.  It should be present in your $res array already.

So Page2 would have something like this at the top:

```
if(!isset($_GET['id']){
    //Give an error if the ID isn't in the URL
}

$id = $_GET['id'];

$result = loadFromLDAP($id);

//Do stuff with the resulting $result array
```

loadFromLDAP being a function you would write to get details about a user from LDAP.  Hope this helps get you on the right track.